# Shortcut to get the first word of the previous command in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, terminator

I am using terminator for my terminal so maybe there is a specific shortcut for this on it.

Instead of hitting the up arrow and hitting crtl+w to delete the last word of the previous command (So I am left with just the command itself (first word of the previous command in this case), syntax is "[command] [string]")

I want a simple shortcut to give me the first word of the previously entered command.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Alt+.</kbd> to get a previous word. It defaults to the last word, so prefix it with the index of the word you want: <kbd>Alt+0</kbd> <kbd>Alt+.</kbd>. You can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the alt+. but I can't get the first word with your input.

Comment: It's zero, not O, right?

Comment: Works for me: Type `echo a b`, press Enter. Press Alt+0, then press Alt+. and you will get `echo` in your command line.

Comment: thats "<alt> <$number> <alt> <dot>" for anyone who has to squint to see that dot at the end

Answer (score 0):

Run this binding :

```
$ bind '"'$(tput kf5)'":"'$(tput cuu1)$'\x01\ef \x0b"'
```

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to get last command name only.